# RegEx for matching the last line

Tags: regex, performance, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I'm configing a RegEx (so it won't be that easy to switch into raw code for this requirement), to get the last line of input, if I use `/.*$/` it gets quite slow for some inputs, e.g. js`'1'.repeat(1e6)+'\n2'`. Is there fast way to get the last line?

Also, if it's not a good idea to use RegEx as a matching config, is there better suggestions?

Comment: You could use ```tail -n 1 path``` in bash.

Comment: Can you post an example of input, what you expect, and what you actually get? Also can you post a tag for what language you are y=using?

Comment: A good regex engine should be able to optimise its matcher when the expression ends in `$`. But no, there's no alternative regex that does achieve the same but with better performance.

Comment: When you put `.*` in front of an EOS anchor, it will still match each line in the string, there is no getting around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optimized expression for finding the final line of a large input string would be the one that introduces explicit boundaries:

```
(?m)^.*\z
```

In languages like PHP it would be written as `/^.*\z/m` (`/`s are delimiters and `m` is multiline flag). The caret `^` makes engine not to go through `.*` (evil) regex if it is not matched. So we have defined a very well known boundary, not only for us to recognize the desired part but also for engines and their builtin optimizations.

The performance of this regex depends on number of lines of input string. So an input string [like yours](https://regex101.com/r/jws9VC/1) isn't a problem at all but something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/jws9VC/2) would bring some attention.

In both cases it performs fast and doesn't come to a failure.

Comment: I tested in node, and `\z` is not supported. Yet `/(?<=^|\n).*$/` runs fast, so there's optimization for backward assert in node?

Comment: Sorry, I removed referring to JS in my answer. Node.js runs on top of V8 engine. If you think it runs fast, it may be the case about some internal optimizations but it is important to see what kind of input string it was run against. Also check `^.+(?![^])` with no `m` flag.

Comment: I guess `/(?<=^|\n).*$/` is optimized into `/(?:^|\n)(?<res>.*$)/` returning the `res`, or optimized when the check is of fixed length. `^.+(?![^])` performs bad at `'1'.repeat(1e6)+'\n2'` too

Comment: It should be fixed length opt. `/(?<=^|\n|3*).*$/.exec('1'.repeat(1e6)+'\n2')[0]` is slow

Comment: No it should be special optimization for backward scanning, it seems possible to do that backwards

Comment: Also care that lookbehinds aren't supported by all major browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try some tests ...
***String target =  127,000 bytes, with 1,057 lines***

```
Regex1:   .*$
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    12.74 s,   12743.09 ms,   12743087 µs
Matches per sec:   392


Regex2:   .*\z
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    12.77 s,   12765.26 ms,   12765260 µs
Matches per sec:   391


Regex3:   \z
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    6.41 s,   6410.85 ms,   6410854 µs
Matches per sec:   779


Regex4:   $
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    6.36 s,   6364.10 ms,   6364098 µs
Matches per sec:   785
```